# Using the R forestplot package, is there a way to assign variable colors to boxes?

Tags: r, plot, colors, r-forestplot

As an example, I will use the code from the R forestplot vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html):

```
library(forestplot)
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
  c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
    "4", "14", "3", "1", 
    "8", NA, NA),
  c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
    "11", "20", "7", "7", 
    "10", NA, NA),
  c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02", NA, "0.53"))

forestplot(tabletext, 
       cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
       is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
       clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
       xlog=TRUE, 
       col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

Rather than having all the boxes be the same color, I would like to color the boxes based on the value of another variable.  I modified the example code, adding another column ("test") to cochrane_from_rmeta and would like to color the boxes based on the value of "test".  I would imagine the code should look like this:

```
library(forestplot)
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
    test = c(NA,NA,1,3,1,7,4,9,6,NA,2)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper", "test"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
  c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
    "4", "14", "3", "1", 
    "8", NA, NA),
  c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
    "11", "20", "7", "7", 
    "10", NA, NA),
  c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02", NA, "0.53"))

forestplot(tabletext, 
       cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
       is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
       clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
       xlog=TRUE, 
       col=fpColors(box=cochrane_from_rmeta$test,line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

However, doing this makes the boxes disappear.  Is there a way to color the boxes based on the value of "test", or is forestplot unable to handle a vector of colors?

Comment: `?fpColors` tells us: _"If you have several values per row in a forestplot you can set a color to a vector where the first value represents the first line/box, second the second line/box etc."_ So I don't think you can do what you want without modification of the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using your own custom line drawing function:

```
library(forestplot)
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
  c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
    "4", "14", "3", "1", 
    "8", NA, NA),
  c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
    "11", "20", "7", "7", 
    "10", NA, NA),
  c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02", NA, "0.53"))

fn <- local({
  i = 0
  no_lines <- sum(!is.na(cochrane_from_rmeta$mean))
  b_clrs = colorRampPalette(colors=c("pink", "blue"))(no_lines)
  l_clrs = colorRampPalette(colors=c("blue", "pink"))(no_lines)

  function(..., clr.line, clr.marker){
    i <<- i + 1
    fpDrawNormalCI(..., clr.line = l_clrs[i], clr.marker = b_clrs[i])
  }
})
forestplot(tabletext, fn.ci_norm = fn,
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
           clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE, 
           col=fpColors(summary="royalblue"))
```

[image]

Note that I don't use the test-column, this should do be enough for you to figure out the remainder.

Comment: sorry for dredging up this question again but I'm stuck on amending the above code to get alternative colours for each box in graph. Fairly straightforward but I can't figure it out. Imagine you have three boxes on the graph, the code might be something like this? ......col=fpColors(box="royalblue", "green", "yellow"), ......  This isn't working for me though. :(

Comment: @user2363642 - the fpColors doesn't allow that at the moment. You need to make your own draw function to handle this case. In above example just set the `b_clrs=c("royalblue","green","yellow")` and your fine. It's a little hacky but it'll do the job.